# My exported fbx file size has gone from about 8 mb to 403 mb. Is there anyway to compress this down to a more reasonable size?

Tags: export, .fbx

The other day I finished up a test character I was working on and wanted to import it into Unity. When I exported the fbx, blender exported it fairly quickly and was only around 7.8 mb in size. Today I made some changes to the mesh and added 40 frames of animation and the file size jumped to 403 mb. I've tried exporting just the mesh and animations (no armatures, cameras, lamps, etcs) and the file size hasn't changed. I've also checked for other duplicated objects, but it looks like my character is the only top level object in the scene. I was hoping someone had some tips or advice on how to reduce this file size?

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the animation is the main source of file size. Eliminating cameras and lamps will have negligible effect on file weight, compared to mesh data and animation.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, but I wasn't expecting 40 frames to blow up the file size like that.

Comment: Depends on animation type or how it is being exported, simple motion might not be heavy deformations or shapes might require more, all depends on how it is getting exported. I'm not an animation nor FBX expert though

Comment: What do you mean just "40 frames"? I see a full rigged character with not only shapekys but an armature complete with a whole several dozen actions and animations, that is not 40 frames certainly not and gonna fit in 7 mb size

Comment: I meant I added 40 additional frames and it jumped to 403. I did end up figuring out what happened. I set the render on my subsurf modifier way too high after redoing the eyes and had too many triangles. I dropped the render back down to a reasonable number and that seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: It's due to the multi resolution or subdivision modifier.